# How does a computer store decimal point values?

Tags: binary, hex, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I have a few questions:

1. Computers only use 1s and 0s to represent numbers. Then how does it represent a decimal point like 5.512.
2. The computer doesn't know whether we are entering an ASCII value or just a random binary for it to process. In earlier days, people used to program using hex and binary. How would they achieve in outputting a character on the screen. Apart from that how does the computer understand that 65(decimal) is not a number but a capital A?

Comment: google first, SO second. These are basic questions you can answer yourself.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: SO doesn't have the answer to the second yet I guess, can you provide me with a link. Thanks for the other one.

Comment: In the days when people programmed in binary, they didn't have screens. All output was similarly in binary. Blinkenlichten. Or it was written on cards, or on a printer. A programmer knew what he was printing, and so interpreted the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first point, see the [IEEE754-1985 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for one approach (probably the most common).

For your second point, you need to realise that there is a disconnect between a value and the representation of that value. A value can be stored in one way and interpreted in a host of different ways.

For example, the octets `0x30, 0x31` may be represented as the value `0x3031` in big-endian 16-bit values, `0x3130` in little-endian or the character sequence `'0', '1'` in ASCII. It would be something else again if it was treated as EBCDIC or fixed point values.

It all comes down to how you *interpret* the data.

Comment: I agree that it is interpreted in a different way, but you are talking about disconnects between 2 values. Unfortunately a disconnect can only be a 1 or a 0. Then ky question is, how does the computer recognize that its a disconnect and not a value?

Comment: @Total, you're trying to reconcile two different levels of abstraction. That's done with a mapping of some sort. The computer has no concept of "a disconnect" as you seem to envisage it. You give it data, you tell it how to interpret that data, there's no intelligence involved. You don't give the CPU a 4-byte block of memory and ask it to figure out what it is - you _tell_ it what it is and, if you tell it wrong, woe betide all who use your program :-)

Comment: Lol. Okay, now I understand it. Thanks a lot @paxdiablo

Comment: I'll mark your answer as the correct answer, but can you help me out with what you mentioned as "a mapping of some sort"?

Comment: @Total, I mean that video cards will map the octet 65 to a certain pattern on the screen, `A`. CPUs handling IEEE754 will treat four-octet floats and eight-octet doubles in a certain manner when manipulating them. The ALU inside your CPU will know how to handle 16-bit little-ending shorts so that it can successfully add them. That's what I meant by mapping, the interpretation of the raw content.

Comment: That explained it completely. Thanks a lot.